# Sum of amount not Showing Just Display Last amount ?? PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Help me please the code showing just recent Amount Not the Total Sum.
Help Please??

````
<div class="pt-3 pb-2">
                                                       @if(count($activities) > 0 )
                                                              @foreach($activities as $activity)
                                                               @php($sum_ref = $activity->amount)
                                                             @endforeach 
                                                              <h5>Total Earning:{{env('CURRENCY').' '.$sum_ref}}</h5>
                                                         @else
                                                           <h5>Total Earning: {{ env('CURRENCY') .' 0'}}</h5>  
                                                          @endif
                                                       </div> ```
````

Comment: what is `$activities`? a Collection of Models?

Comment: change `$sum_ref = $activity->amount` to `$sum_ref += $activity->amount`

Comment: @lagbox user details amount invested name etc

Comment: @jibsteroos Error when i add +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$activities` is a Collection you don't need to do any looping. Collections have a `sum` method:

```
<h5>Total Earning:{{ config('app.currency').' '. $activities->sum('amount')) }}</h5>
```

You should avoid calling `env` outside of config files. Just add a configuration key to `config/app.php` that uses your ENV variable:

```
'currency' => env('CURRENCY', '$'),
```

Then you can use the config system as in the exmaple code above.

Comment: THanks You soo Much FIX @lagbox